# Simplify equation according to trigonometric rules

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, symbolic-math

I was wondering if there was a way to automatically display cosine/sine of the sum of symbolic variables. I'm multiplying symbolic matrices and in one cell of the result I have something like

```
cos(A)*cos(B)-sin(A)*sin(B)
```

where `A` and `B` are my symbolic variables. Is there a way to automatically display in every occurrence of that the actual cosine of the sum such that the cosine identity is given?

```
cos(A+B)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`simplify`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html)

```
syms A B
simplify(cos(A)*cos(B)-sin(A)*sin(B))
ans =
cos(A + B)
```